How can I list the names of various sheets in a "recap" summary sheet in Excel?
I have 20 sheets; each sheet name is a number (sheet 1 name is 51646, sheet 2 name is 51647 and so on).
my last sheet is a summary of data for each sheet number.
I am trying to figure out what function I need to use to list each sheet name? I know how to pull the data, but not the sheet name from the tab of the sheet.
I need to pull the sheet name from the tab on each sheet into my summary sheet. So when I change the sheet tab name, the name of the sheet in my summary sheet changes too.
I don't want a macro, just a function.

Please show your current function code. Note that this is not a script-writing service. Show us the code you have and what you have tried, and we can help provide suggestions what you can improve or correct to get it to do what you need.

See https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-quick-ways-to-get-a-list-of-all-worksheet-names-in-an-excel-workbook/, https://www.statology.org/excel-list-sheet-names/

I think that the easiest way is to write a UDF function in VBA, which can then be called in a worksheet. Its argument is the position number of the worksheet in the workbook, that is, the number 1 is the worksheet from the left.
The function code must be placed in the standard module.
Function Shname(idx As Long) As String
    If idx <= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then
        Shname = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(idx).Name
    End If
End Function

In a worksheet, for example, you can call this function like this:
=Shname(ROW(A1)+0*RAND())

This will be the name of the first sheet.
RAND function is added to recalculate function when sheet name is changed.


woah, that is much more than i can undestand. I am not that advanced, but you have the set up i am trying to accomplish. you have 3 sheets named 156-257-358 and teh summary. what I am looking for is the function or formula that would pull these 3 sheet names and list it excatly like you did.

I have tried the formula you have listed next to it (=SHname(Row(A1)+o*Rand()), but it did not bring up my sheet number. the result was #NAME?

@Jean you need to make the function first, open Visual basics (Alt + F11), on the left there should be a navigation menu with all your open workbooks and sheets; search for VBAProject (Insert workbookname); below it you'll see 'Microsoft Excel Objects' and 'Modules', Rightclick the modules folder, and choose 'insert -> module'; Now you should have Module 1, double click this one, you'll get a white text screen; Paste the function text (in the answer above) over there.

@Excellor, thank you very much for your assistance, I hope it will work out now.

@Excellor Thank you both!!! was able to make it work. just had a hard time to open the VBA with alt+F11 (this did not work for me) so had to change the ribbon option. One more question : do you have to go thru this extra step to create a VBA code or is there a way to just enter a formula ?

Formulas based on Excel itself are quite complex, you have received a suggestion in the comment from @DrMoishe Pippik. This function in VBA is quite simple and once you type it into your workbook, you can use it like any Excel function.

@MGonet thanks for mentioning the suggestion from DrMoishe Pippik. I did not realize there was an answer to my question there. Appreciate your help/input on this!
